# Reschedule crontab job automatically

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

I have jobs in my server machine scheduled which look for files in FTP and then does load in file to mysql. Many times files come late on FTP and I have to run the jobs manually. Is there any way I can reschedule the job with some shell script if file is not present on FTP?

Comment: Why don't you schedule your cronjob more often?

Comment: its a one time job for a day. once file loaded today it should not run today it should run tomorrow.

Comment: Maybe you  can create a script that reads the `crontab` and executes its lines sequentially. It would involve executing `crontab -l`, reading its output, cleaning the first section (`* * *...`) and then running the rest.

Comment: Maybe you should post your script. I think what you want is a simple logic like: if file is present proceed, else wait 5 minutes and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this what you looking for ([incrond](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/))
He can monitor a folder or file and when it's modified, and it can trigger a job.

Comment: thanks but I need something where both the file and time I can check. I don't want to run my before a specified time even though file is available.